# É possível retornar o id do ultimo dado cadastrado com django Model Form

Tags: python-3.x, django

Galera estou com uma dúvida.

Estou usando Django e gostaria de saber se tem como retornar o id do dado cadastrado com o ModelForm, exemplo quando der um model.save() conseguir recuperar o id desse cara que acabou de ser cadastrado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode pegar o `id` do registro que vc acabou de cadastrar, digamos que vc tenha um model com o nome de `Item`, com os campos `descricao` e `quantidade atual`, entao vc cadastra um item e ja pode pegar, no momento do cadastro, o `id` (o exemplo abaixo foi criado no shell do django):

```
from .models import Item
ultimo_id = Item.objects.create(descricao='teste1', quantidade_atual=10).id
print(ultimo_id)
```

Saída:

```
7
```

Mas se vc quer o `id` do ultimo registro mas não está no momento do cadastro (na verdade essa opção vai funcionar sempre), vc pode fazer:

```
ultimo_id = Item.objects.latest('pk').pk
print(ultimo_id)
```

Saída:

```
7
```

> Editada
>   Conforme indicado nos comentários, o registro está sendo salvo no banco através da função `save()` de um form, nesse caso basta fazer:

```
registro = meu_form.save()
```

Dessa forma voce tera acesso a todos os campos do registro ataves da notação `registro.fieldname`, para imprimir a `pk` que, na verdade, é o `id`, faça:

```
print(registro.id)
```

Saída:

```
7
```

> Nova edição
>   Se por acaso, por qq motivo vc ja fizer o save sem atribuir o retorno a uma  variável (como no seu exemplo: `meu_form.save()`) e precisar pegar os campos do registro salvo, faça:

```
registro = meu_form.instance
```

Comment: Então só que no caso eu estou criando um novo registro com ModelForm do django; ex: `meu_form.save()` e aqui recuperar o id que foi criado no banco.

Comment: Ok, editei a resposta e acrescentei essa opcao.

Comment: Opa agora sim funcionou, valeu Sidon. Ajudou bastante cara.

Comment: Legal, se puder, dê um upvote!

Comment: Estou acrescentando mais um detalhe para quando vc ja fez o `save()`.